# Custom Credential Provider: logon users who are not displayed on logon screen

Tags: windows-10, credential-providers

We're implementing a HW token-based custom credential provider for Windows 10, based on `ICredentialProvider`, `ICredentialProviderCredential` and alike.

This works fine for users that **are displayed** as tiles on the logon screen: when the token gets plugged in, we ask for reenumeration of the credentials by calling `ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged`, and then specify in `ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount` that we've got a credential to be set as default and be performed auto logon with.

The problem is that on Windows 10 not all local users are displayed in the tiles list, just those who are currently logged on, plus the last user who has logged on earlier.
If we return a credential for a user **not displayed** in the tiles, but with a valid SID and specify it as default and to be logged on automatically - nothing happens, ie. the credential's `ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization` is not invoked.

How can we perform auto logon for a user not displayed?

The built-in fingerprint-based provider can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have had to walk around this and pass it. I have been started with Windows Vista and later added a lot of  code and logic to support new features of Windows 10, like this one you are talking about.

You must enumerate at `GetCredentialCount`/`GetCredentialAt` another one "empty" tile which is not linked to any user.

Then you can modify it and do automatic logon using any user.

Comment: Do you mean returning `S_FALSE` from `ICredentialProviderCredential2::GetUserSid`?

Comment: According to the Microsoft's [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovidercredential2-getusersid), yes. You can even do not support the `ICredentialProviderCredential2` interface for that tile.